# Regex: group that must exist but it's unknown at advance where it will be

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need to get `href` argument value, but only for those `<link>` tags which has `type='image/x-icon'` attribute (by other words, favicon tags):

```html
// Below ones must be parsed
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#" />

// Below ones must be ignored
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.html">
<link rel="search" href="search.html">
<link rel="help" href="help.html">
```

The problem is `type="image/x-icon"` could be before `href="#"` or after it, but exactly one of these cases. How I can express it in regular expression from JavaScript?

[Regex fiddle with my try](https://regex101.com/r/tujqBF/1)

Comment: I'd use an HTML parser or DOM traversal. [Regex just can't do HTML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Are you using Node or browser JS?

Comment: @ggorlen, NodeJS.

Comment: Check out an HTML parser like [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/) instead of regex.

Comment: @ggorlen, it will save a lot of time... Thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it with a single regex, it's possible to use a [lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Lookahead_assertion) to verify that the `link` tag contains `type="image/x-icon"` before going on to capture the `href` value.

Something like:

`/<link (?=[^>]*type="image\/x-icon")[^>]* href="([^"]+)" [^>]*>/`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) API instead

```js
let str = `
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.html">
<link rel="search" href="search.html">
<link rel="help" href="help.html">`

let parser = new DOMParser()
let parsed = parser.parseFromString(str,"text/html")

let links = parsed.getElementsByTagName('link')

console.log(Object.values(links).filter(val=> val.type === 'image/x-icon'))
```

Comment: Just say no to using regex for HTML parsing! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use an or `|` in your regex like so:

```
/<link (?:(?:.* type="image\/x-icon" .* href="([^"]+)" .*)|(?:.* href="([^\"]+)" .* type="image\/x-icon" .*))\/>/
```

In other words, you have a link tag with either the type attribute followed by the href, or the href attribute followed by the type.

You may need to check the resultant groups and get the one that has a defined value.